# Ripple effect not working when call in item recycler view with evetn replace fragment

Tags: android, ripple

I have recycler view in a fragment. when click item in recycler view I call method replace fragment.
I custom a ripple.xml to background item recyclerview but it not show animation when replace.
Here is my code:
custom_bg.xml for api < 20

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

custom_bg.xml ripple effect

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white">
    </item>
</ripple>
```

item.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/game_ll_item_list"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mTvScore"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTvNameTeamA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_tv_item_team_size"
            tools:text="朝日南" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTvNameTeamASmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20pt"
            tools:text="（東東京）" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTvScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/game_tv_item_score_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/game_tv_item_score_margin_left_right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/game_tv_item_score_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="2-8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mImgArrow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mTvScore"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTvNameTeamB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_tv_item_team_size"
            tools:text="ABC工科" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTvNameTeamBSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20pt"
            tools:text="（東東京）" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mImgArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="@dimen/game_img_list_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_pink"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mViewLine"
        style="@style/CommonLine"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in myadapter.class i call event

```js
 private class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       
        private final RelativeLayout mRoot;

        public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mRoot = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mRoot);
            mRoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and in myfragment.class I call

```js
 mAdapter = new GameListAdapter(mContext, new GameListAdapter.OnGameAdapterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                if (position < mObjects.size()) {
                    Object object = mObjects.get(position);
                    if (object instanceof Schedule) {
                        if (getParentFragment() instanceof BaseContainerFragment) {
                            if (!isItemClicked) {
                                isItemClicked = true;
                                ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(GameDetailFragment_.builder().mSchedule((Schedule) object).build(), true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

```js
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0);
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.mFrameContainer, fragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

I tried post delay it show animation but it very lag.
How I can fix it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: did it work for you? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

or this

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

or this

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

or this

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

in your parent layout of item.xml of recyclerview this will generate ripple effect automatically.